# Problem setting focus to validationsummary control after validation

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I have a validationsummary control which displays the summary of a few validationrequired controls and all of them belong to a validationgroup.

My submit button also has the same validationgroup so it validates everything upon it being clicked.

The problem i am having is setting the focus to the validationsummary control after validation occurs when my submit button is clicked. 
The focus goes to the top of my webform.

I need the focus to be put at the validationsummary control.
How do i achieve this?

FYI:SetFocusOnError="true" did not work.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: make some sample page and put some control there from ur current page and check if working? otherwise post that sample page code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://forums.asp.net/t/967952.aspx.
I haven't verified it. But the last reply said it's working.

Also, you could try `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` so that at least the focus is the same as before it's posted back.

Comment: Great suggestion if your validation summary is near the submit button

Answer (score 1):

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
  Text="Button" OnClientClick="SummaryFocus();" />
```

**Script:**

```
function SummaryFocus() {
    Page_ClientValidate();
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < Page_ValidationSummaries.length; i++) 
    {
        if (!Page_ValidationSummaries[i].isvalid) 
        {                
            window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById(Page_ValidationSummaries[i].id).offsetTop);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have customvalidator doing a postback?

Comment: no.here is my asp.net code:
<asp:ValidationSummary class="error-details" ID="vsInsertComp" runat="server" HeaderText="There are errors on the page.  Please make the requested corrections before continuing."
                                                                                        DisplayMode="BulletList" ValidationGroup="ProfileInsertComp" Width="80%"></asp:ValidationSummary>

Comment: may i know what difference a custom validator would make in this context?

Comment: A full postback, which takes you to the top of the screen if not using Ajax.

Comment: I tested this code with a few validators that had display=none.  It worked with the ValidationSummary at the top or bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  If you actually look at the validation summary markup in a browser it is just the error messages for each validator that has gone off in its validation group.  You can't put focus on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tips added on this Connect issue report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/342104/maintainscrollpositiononpostback-and-validationsummary (sorry for the cut and paste URI, for some reason I can't add the link properly).

It's all a bit of a hack, but it could help you out.